# Installed Apricity OS, but only has barebone GNOME desktop after restart

Tags: gnome, desktop-environment, distribution-choice, theme

[image]I installed Apricity OS as guest in my VMware, and installed it successfully.
During installation, the desktop was as Apricity customized. (Fonts, themes, icons, shell, etc.) But when I restarted it after installation, I was greeted with plain GNOME desktop, as attached. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you login choose 'Gnome on Xorg' instead of 'Gnome'.

The issue is that when you choose 'Gnome' it's gnome on wayland (that's still a bit buggy), while 'Gnome on Xorg' uses xorg (that's an old and more stable software).